# Image not found in webpage served with node.js and express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm trying to serve a very simple html page with one image. I'm using node.js and express. The html loads, but the image does not. Instead i am given the error `GET https://localhost:3000/stockMarketPhoto.jpg 404 (Not Found)` The image is in the same directory as everything else is. Somewhere I saw suggested that `app.use(express.static('public'));` is supposed to help with this, but no dice. I've tried both `<img src="stockMarketPhoto.jpg">` and `<img src="https://localhost:3000/stockMarketPhoto.jpg">`. How can I get the image in my HTML page to load?

Here's the html in question

```
  <body>
    <img src="stockMarketPhoto.jpg">
  </body>
```

Here's the javascript.

```
const https = require('https');
const express = require("express")
const fs = require('fs');
let app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("listening on 3000");
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('connected');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First i recommend you read this from the express docs.
[Serving Static files in express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

and in here:

```
<img src="stockMarketPhoto.jpg">
```

you are missing a '/' should look like this:

```
<img src="/stockMarketPhoto.jpg">
```

Your image should be inside the public folder in your app. What i do is usually put an Image, Javascript, and css folder inside my public folder and import them like this:

```
src='/Image/example.jpg'
src='/Javascript/example.js'
src='/css/master.css'
```

Basically when you tell express to serve your static files in the public folder, express then interprets the above example like this.

```
'public/Image/example.jpg'
```

Comment: when you say 'public folder' do you mean the root directory everything is in which is what i (sillily) assumed when i read the express documentation originally, or do i make a folder inside that called 'public' and put my resources in there?

Comment: creater a public folder in the same directory as your app.js or index and inside that public folder put your image.